# Apollo with AWS Cloudfront. Not getting playground query client

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, apollo-server

I am running Apollo server in the ec2 instance, due to update the https URL I connect my ec2 server with Cloudfront so that I can get the https url. Now when I open the URL I am not getting a playground query client.

Ec2 server is running 4000 port, and also Cloudfront HTTP port opens 4000.

Here is my Cloudfront url look like https://text+cloudfront.net/graphql I am not getting any query client. I just getting an auth error that is returned from the server.

But If I request ec2 URL directly it works http://ec2-3-3939-93-217.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4000/graphql

Comment: did you find a solution to this?